# React - index starts after array is filtered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some products that I am trying to display in my app. Some of the products are marked as featured and I want to exclude those products from this section. I also want to show only the first 4 non-featured products. I am using `map` to iterate over the products and `filter` to remove the featured ones. Within my map function, I am adding a conditional to only display the product if it's `index` is less than or equal to `3`(to show the first 4). This is partially working, except that the products that I am filtering out are still getting assigned an index and since the first two posts are marked as featured, it's only displaying 2 products rather than 4 since the first non-featured post has an index of `2`.

```
{products.filter(product => product.featured == false).map((product, index) => {
    if (index >= 3) {
        console.log(index);
        return (
            <div key={index} className="product"><Product /></div>
        );
    }
})}
```

Comment: Show some example data for products that allow us to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your code and some test data:

```
const products = [
{
    name: "fp1",
    featured: true
},
{
    name: "p1",
    featured: false
},
{
    name: "p2",
    featured: false
},
{
    name: "fp2",
    featured: true
},
{
    name: "p3",
    featured: false
},
{
    name: "p4",
    featured: false
},
{
    name: "fp3",
    featured: true
},
{
    name: "p5",
    featured: false
}
];

var results = products
.filter(product => product.featured == false)
.map((product, index) => {
    if (index >= 3) {
    console.log(index);
    // I return product.name instead of a div for testing purposes
    return product.name;
    }
});
```

I get the following output:

```
[ undefined, undefined, undefined, 'p4', 'p5' ]
```

The reason is because the `map` function always returns a value on every iteration, however, you have a conditional `if` that means values will only be returned if the `index >= 3`. This means the first 3 items are undefined.

What you want to do is:

```
var results = products
.filter(product => product.featured == false)
.slice(0, 4)
.map(product => {
    return product.name;
});
```

This filters out the `featured` products, then takes the first 4 from the resulting array, then maps these 4 products to a `string` or in your case, a `div`.

The result of the above code is:

```
[ 'p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4' ]
```

This also works if there are less than 4 non-featured products.

It's also worth noting that you shouldn't use the array index as a key if you can help it, see the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys). If you have `product.id` then that would be good to use.

Also try not to use `var` and go for `const` (or `let` if you plan to reassign the variable) instead, as there are issues with variable scope when using `var`([see here](https://dev.to/sarah_chima/var-let-and-const--whats-the-difference-69e)).

An improved function would be something like this:

```
const results = products
.filter(p => !p.featured)
.slice(0, 4)
.map(p => (
    <div key={p.id} className="product">
        <Product />
    </div>
));
```